# Android Studio recycleview to detail not working

Tags: android, android-studio

I have any problem in show detail class from recycleview,
recycleview is show but detail not function,
I do not understand how to make on click with position in recycle view,

this is my ListBerita.java

```html
 
        
        stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("response ", response);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("berita");
                    for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray.length(); a++) {
                        JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(a);
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("id_berita", json.getString("id_berita"));
                        map.put("id_pos", json.getString("id_pos"));
                        map.put("nama_pos", json.getString("nama_pos"));
                        map.put("gambar_berita", json.getString("gambar_berita"));
                        map.put("berita", json.getString("berita"));
                        list_data.add(map);
                        AdapterList adapter = new AdapterList(ListBerita.this, list_data);
                        beritalist.setAdapter(adapter);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }



<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ListBerita.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

}
```

and this is my adapter

```html
package baru.azoel.ayomuncak.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import baru.azoel.ayomuncak.DetailBerita;
import baru.azoel.ayomuncak.ListBerita;
import baru.azoel.ayomuncak.R;

/**
 * Created by azoel.
 */
public class AdapterList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterList.ViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_data;

    public AdapterList(ListBerita beritaActivity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_data) {
        this.context = beritaActivity;
        this.list_data = list_data;

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_berita, null);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load("http://marimuncak.000webhostapp.com/images/" + list_data.get(position).get("gambar_berita"))
                .crossFade()
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .into(holder.imgberita);
        holder.txtnama.setText(list_data.get(position).get("nama_pos"));
        holder.txtberita.setText(list_data.get(position).get("berita"));

       
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list_data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtberita;
        ImageView imgberita;
        TextView txtnama;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtnama = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtnama);
            txtberita = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtberita);
            imgberita = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgberita);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you want handler event click to position item in Recyclerview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class AdapterList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterList.ViewHolder>{

Context context;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_data;

public AdapterList(ListBerita beritaActivity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_data) {
    this.context = beritaActivity;
    this.list_data = list_data;

}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_berita, null);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(context)
            .load("http://marimuncak.000webhostapp.com/images/" + list_data.get(position).get("gambar_berita"))
            .crossFade()
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(holder.imgberita);
    holder.txtnama.setText(list_data.get(position).get("nama_pos"));
    holder.txtberita.setText(list_data.get(position).get("berita"));
   holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
     onItemClickListener.onItemClick(position);
   }
});

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list_data.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txtberita;
    ImageView imgberita;
    TextView txtnama;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtnama = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtnama);
        txtberita = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtberita);
        imgberita = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgberita);
    }
}

   public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener){
    this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
}

OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

  public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
}
```

your Activity. in Oncreate()

```
 public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterList.OnItemClickListener {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
     your_adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

  @Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
   // code here
}
}
```

Comment: do you have a link that i can learn about recycleview and detail class with mysql?

Comment: you can refer: https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

In your `onBindViewHolder` method add a click listener for your `itemView`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(context)
            .load("http://marimuncak.000webhostapp.com/images/" + list_data.get(position).get("gambar_berita"))
            .crossFade()
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(holder.imgberita);
    holder.txtnama.setText(list_data.get(position).get("nama_pos"));
    holder.txtberita.setText(list_data.get(position).get("berita"));

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          //Do something here with position
       }
    });

}
```

If you wish to add item click in your activity/fragment class rather than adapter class, there are multiple ways to do it. One of them is written below.

Create a class `ItemClickSupport`

***ItemClickSupport.java***

```
public class ItemClickSupport {
private final RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
private OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClickListener;
private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
            mOnItemClickListener.onItemClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
        }
    }
};
private View.OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(v);
            return mOnItemLongClickListener.onItemLongClicked(mRecyclerView, holder.getAdapterPosition(), v);
        }
        return false;
    }
};
private RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener mAttachListener
        = new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
        if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
            view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        }
        if (mOnItemLongClickListener != null) {
            view.setOnLongClickListener(mOnLongClickListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {

    }
};

private ItemClickSupport(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
    mRecyclerView.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, this);
    mRecyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
}

public static ItemClickSupport addTo(RecyclerView view) {
    ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
    if (support == null) {
        support = new ItemClickSupport(view);
    }
    return support;
}

public static ItemClickSupport removeFrom(RecyclerView view) {
    ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
    if (support != null) {
        support.detach(view);
    }
    return support;
}

public ItemClickSupport setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mOnItemClickListener = listener;
    return this;
}

public ItemClickSupport setOnItemLongClickListener(OnItemLongClickListener listener) {
    mOnItemLongClickListener = listener;
    return this;
}

private void detach(RecyclerView view) {
    view.removeOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
    view.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, null);
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {

    void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
}

public interface OnItemLongClickListener {

    boolean onItemLongClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v);
}
}
```

The you can use this class for all your `recyclerViews` like below

```
ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
            //Do something here with position
        }
    });
```

You can even override `onItemLongClicked`if you have different gestures for different navigation

Comment: do you have a link that i can learn about recycleview and detail class with mysql?